# Activity is blocked whenever soft keyboard is shown or hidden

Tags: android, performance, dialog, keyboard, lag

I am having an `Activity` with two `RecyclerView` with big amount of data.

Now I'm showing a `Dialog` on this Activity, Dialog is having multiple `EditText` and `Spinner` in it. so as soon as I start typing and keyboard appears at that time my UI is blocked. And same as when I hide keyboard at that time also my UI is blocked for couple of seconds. And ultimately I frequently get ANRs.

And yes If I comment out `RecyclerViews` from my `Activity` then same `Dialog` is working fine without any lag.

So how to overcome this problem can anyone help me in addressing this issue.

Comment: No code , no solution. ! Code pls

Comment: Try to load your data on background thread/async task and if your data is really - really big, you can divide the data with paging system

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono Data loading is not any problem, data are loaded correctly on my activity but problem occurs when I show dialog and start typing in any of its edit texts at that time android keyboard blocks my main activity. In short showing and hiding of keyboard in my dialog blocks my main activity from which dialog is being shown.

Comment: @Stallion, I've an activity which is having recycler views with huge data and I'm showing a simple dialog from this activity but whenever keyboard is shown or hidden on dialog, it blocks the main activity from which it was shown.